# How to use `[[` and `$` as a function?

Tags: r

I know I can do this:

```
x <- list(a=1, b=1)
y <- list(a=1)
JSON <- rep(list(x,y),10000)
sapply(JSON, "[[", "a")
```

However, I struggled at use `$` in the same way

```
sapply(JSON, "$", "a")
sapply(JSON, "$", a)
```

Also, is it possible to use operator as a function like other languages?

e.g. `a + b`  is equivalent to `(+)(a, b)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, you just need to use an anonymous function with `$`. I would *guess* that this has something to do with the fact that `$`'s arguments are [*never* evaluated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18228613/1478381)...

```
sapply(JSON, function(x) `$`( x , "a" ) )
```

And to answer your second question... Yes, all binary arithmetic operators can be specified using back ticks, like so...

```
a <- 2 
b <- 3

# a + b
`+`( a , b )
[1] 5
# a ^ b
`^`( a , b )
[1] 8
# a - b
`-`( a , b )
[1] -1
```

Comment: Actually regular quotes usually work as well: `'+'(1,1)
[1] 2`

Comment: @DWin Possibly not always though... From the bottom of `?Quotes`: *Such identifiers are also known as syntactic names and may be used directly in R code. Almost always, other names can be used provided they are quoted. The preferred quote is the backtick (`\``), and `deparse` will normally use it, but under many circumstances single or double quotes can be used (as a character constant will often be converted to a name). One place where backticks may be essential is to delimit variable names in formulae: see `formula`.*