# what is `[[` looking for in this sapply example?

Tags: r, sapply

A followup to this [How to use `[[` and `$` as a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762408/how-to-use-and-as-a-function) question:  I started playing a bit with the original setup (reduced the size from 10000 to 3 for simplicity)

```
JSON <- rep(list(x,y),3)
x <- list(a=1, b=1)
y <- list(a=1)
JSON <- rep(list(x,y),3)
sapply(JSON, "[[", "a")
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
sapply(JSON,"[[",'b')
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
[1] 1

[[6]]
NULL

sapply(JSON,'[[',1)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
sapply(JSON,'[[',2)
Error in FUN(X[[2L]], ...) : subscript out of bounds
```

That I think  I understand -- searching for "b" is different from demanding the existence of a second element.  But then, I created a deeper list:

```
NOSJ<-rep(list(JSON),3)

sapply(NOSJ,'[[',1)
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
a 1    1    1   
b 1    1    1   
sapply(NOSJ,'[[',2)
$a
[1] 1

$a
[1] 1

$a
[1] 1
```

And now my head's hurting.  Can someone expand on what `[[` (or its `sapply` method) is doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could think of sapply and lapply as a for-loop that operates on seq_along(NOSJ) as an index vector.

```
 for( i in seq_along(NOSJ) NOSJ[[i]]  .... then use "[[" with the 3rd argument
```

So the first and second results would be:

```
> NOSJ[[1]][[1]]
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 1

> NOSJ[[2]][[1]]
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 1
```

The difference between `sapply` and `lapply` is that `sapply` attempts to use `simply2array` to return a matrix or array if the dimensions of the returned values are all the same (as they are in this case when using `1`, `3` or `5` as the 3rd argument. Quite honestly I do not know why using 2,4,or 6 as the third argument does not return an atomic vector. I thought it should.

Comment: Technically, it does return a named vector.  `is.vector( sapply( NOSJ, '[[' , 2  ) )` returns `[1] TRUE`. I don't know why it doesn't *look* like a vector though.

Comment: `is.vector` is a misleading test of the structure. Look at `is.vector(list(a=1,b=2))`. Technically lists are vectors but that is not the usual way people use the language.

Comment: I have just noticed that. How can that be? I was just about to post a question to this effect.

Comment: The fundamental distinction is between "atomic" and "recursive".

Comment: I think I had been using R for about 3 years before I stumbled across that one.

Answer (score 3):

`sapply(NOSJ,'[[',1)` returns the first list element of each of the lists passed to `[[` by `sapply` from `NOSJ`. Try...

```
sapply( NOSJ , length )
[1] 6 6 6
```

Makes sense right? So `[[` is operating on the second level lists, the first element of which *always* contain *only* `a` and `b` so are coercible to a matrix. The second element of those lists of 6, *always* contain *only* `a`.

Comment: OK, I think I'm learning :-) .  This did what I expected: `sapply(sapply(NOSJ,'[[',1),'[[',1)`